# `type -a` works even though `-a` not an option

Tags: bash

I could check installed apps with command `type -a`

```
$ type -a python
python is /Users/gaowei/Desktop/Django/learning_log/ll_env/bin/python
python is /Users/gaowei/anaconda3/bin/python
python is /usr/bin/python
```

However, there's no -a options in 'man type'

What's the reason?

Comment: `type` is a bash builtin command. use `help type` or `man bash`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you type `help type` then you will see that `type` does have the `-a` option.